# Generic Interface for React Component and prop value with type inference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I want to create a generic interface to contain a Component and a prop value for it.

The idea is to be able to set different Components that accept different types for the same prop.

The scenario would be something like this:

```js
interface FormComponentProps<T> { initialValueForEdit?: T }

interface FormAFields { valueA: string }

function FormA(props: FormComponentProps<FormAFields>): ReactElement {
  const { initialValueForEdit } = props; // initialValueForEdit has type FormAFields
  ...
}

interface FormBFields { valueB: string }

function FormB(props: FormComponentProps<FormBFields>): ReactElement {
  const { initialValueForEdit } = props; // initialValueForEdit has type FormBFields
  ...
}
```

I tried with the following `FormStateInterface` but the problem happens when trying to render it.

The `formState.valueForEdit` type is not infered from `formState.FormComponent` and then it gives the following error for the `initialValueForEdit` prop when setting it to `formState.valueForEdit`:

`Type 'FormAFields' is not assignable to type 'FormAFields & FormBFields'.`

How could we get TS to infer that the `FormComponent` prop and the `valueForEdit` are constrained to the same type?

```js
interface FormStateInterface<T> {
  valueForEdit?: T;
  FormComponent: (props: FormComponentProps<T>) => ReactElement;
}

type AvailableFormStates =
  FormStateInterface<FormAFields> | FormStateInterface<FormBFields>;

function App(): ReactElement {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState<AvailableFormStates | null>(null);

  // No problem here, valueForEdit type is infered from FormA component props
  const formAValue: FormAFields = { valueA: 'foo' };
  const showFormA = () => setFormState({ FormComponent: FormA, valueForEdit: formAValue });

  // Same as above
  const formBValue: FormBFields = { valueB: 'bar' };
  const showFormB = () => setFormState({ FormComponent: FormB, valueForEdit: formBValue });

  return (
    // Error on initialValueForEdit prop
    // Type 'FormAFields' is not assignable to type 'FormAFields & FormBFields'.
    <div>
      {formState ? <formState.FormComponent initialValueForEdit={formState.valueForEdit} /> : (
        <div>
          <button onClick={showFormA}>Show Form A</button>

          <button onClick={showFormB}>Show Form B</button>
        </div>
      )};
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I searched for an answer to your problem for an hour, and I'm afraid what you are looking for is just not possible with current TypeScript inference capacities (or I'm just not good enough, which is totally possible).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish cannot be done in its current form (or likely ever). This is a consequence of how Typescript was intentionally designed to handle ambiguous functions. Either view the explanation or skip to a possible solution.

### Explanation

Observe the following idea

```js
type Foo = {foo: 'foo'}
type Bar = {bar: 'bar'}
const useFoo = (n: Foo) => null!
const useBar = (s: Bar) => null!
type NumberOrStringInterface = {
  fn: typeof useFoo
} | {
  fn: typeof useBar
}
const someObject: NumberOrStringInterface = {} as any
someObject.fn({foo: 'foo'})
// Argument of type '{ foo: "foo"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.
  Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: "foo"; }' but required in type 'Bar'.

someObject.fn({bar: 'bar'})
// Argument of type '{ bar: "bar"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.
  Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ bar: "bar"; }' but required in type 'Foo'.

someObject.fn({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'})
// No errors
```

This is simply because, Typescript does not know which object is needed in the function, because it does not know which function is actually going to be called at runtime. So it will intersect them both, and in the event that you provide `foo` and `bar` it will still work on either `useFoo` and `useBar`.

Now naturally, in your code it might be subtly obvious that `formState.valueForEdit` will always be aligned with the same function component. But how can the type system know that? Short answer, it won't, and likely ever won't. It would be too expensive for this sort of logical narrowing. Such an issue was logged with regards to a type system that would successively deduce types: [Logical successive type guards · Issue #37258 · microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37258), which also helps demonstrate another example of the problem:

> ```js
> function isNull(a: string | null): a is null {
>   return a == null;
> }
>
> function doStuff(a: string | null, b: string | null) {
>   if (a == null && b == null) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   if (a == null && b != null) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   if (a != null && b == null) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   a; // logically must be `string`, but inferred as `string | null`
>   b; // logically must be `string`, but inferred as `string | null`
>   a.length; // Object is possibly 'null'
> }
> ```
>
> > Making the compiler reason about this sort of thing sounds really cool until you realize how slow it would be to implement. Even in this toy baby case, in order to narrow a the compiler needs to
> >
> > 1. realize that it needs to narrow b at the same time
> > 2. pick up all previous flow control statements in the function that involve a or b
> > 3. Exhaustively analyze the product of union possibilities for a and b at the same time through all of those statements
> >
> > -[**nmain** on Mar 9, 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37258#issuecomment-596617000)

There is a comment by RyanCavanaugh (Development lead for the TypeScript) who puts an excellent piece of advice forward:

> As mentioned this would be very complex, plus there are relatively few type domains that can be exhausted by one or two checks. Structuring this code in a way that's more compiler-friendly will also make it more human-friendly so I don't think it's too bad if this doesn't work.
>
> -[**RyanCavanaugh** on Mar 12, 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37258#issuecomment-598342007)

### Solution

Instead of evaluating FormA or FormB in the return value, evaluate the JSX ahead of time and store it.

```js
function App1(): React.ReactElement {
  // JSX.Element and ReactElement are the same type
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState<JSX.Element | null>(null);

  // I have provided this in the case where you need some shared value 
  // between the two different components
  const sharedValue = { sharedValue: true }

  const formAValue: FormAFields = { valueA: 'foo', ...sharedValue };
  const showFormA = () => setFormState(<FormA initialValueForEdit={formAValue} />);

  const formBValue: FormBFields = { valueB: 'bar', ...sharedValue };
  const showFormB = () => setFormState(<FormB initialValueForEdit={formBValue} />);

  return (
    <div>
      {formState ?? (
        <div>
          <button onClick={showFormA}>Show Form A</button>

          <button onClick={showFormB}>Show Form B</button>
        </div>
      )};
    </div>
  );
}
```

[View Example on Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbEREN)